# How to add an insert stored procedure to an API controller with EF Power tools?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, controller

I used EF Core power tools to generate the code below and am trying to create a controller that can call the `InsertAttendee` stored procedure.

I'm not sure how exactly to do this all I know is I need to call `InsertAttendeeAsync` method. I'm not sure how to handle the id, return value, and `cancellationtoken` as they are output parameters which I've never dealt with before. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
[HttpPost("InsertAttendee")]
public async Task<int> InsertAttendeeAsync(Attendee1 request)
{
    Attendee1 Attendee1 = new Attendee1();
    Attendee1.Type = request.Type;
    Attendee1.Person = request.Person;
    Attendee1.FirstName = request.FirstName;
    Attendee1.LastName = request.LastName;
    Attendee1.DateCreated = request.DateCreated;
    Attendee1.DateModified = request.DateModified;
    Attendee1.ModifiedBy = request.ModifiedBy;

    int response = await _context.GetProcedures().InsertAttendeeAsync(Attendee1.DateCreated, Attendee1.DateModified, Attendee1.FirstName, Attendee1.LastName, Attendee1.ModifiedBy, Attendee1.Person, Attendee1.Type, Attendee1.id, Attendee1.returnvalue, Attendee1.cancellationtoken);

    return response;   
}
```

```
namespace *****_API.Models
{
    public partial class Attendee1
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Type { get; set; }
        public int? Person { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

        public virtual Person PersonNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual AttendeeType TypeNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual ExamAttendee1 ExamAttendee1 { get; set; }
        public virtual MeetingAttendee MeetingAttendee { get; set; }
    }
}
```

KATSContextProcedures

```
public virtual async Task<int> InsertAttendeeAsync(DateTime? dateCreated, DateTime? dateModified, string firstName, string lastName, string modifiedBy, int? person, int? type, OutputParameter<int?> id, OutputParameter<int> returnValue = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var parameterid = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "id",
                Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.InputOutput,
                Value = id?._value ?? Convert.DBNull,
                SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int,
            };
    var parameterreturnValue = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "returnValue",
                Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output,
                SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int,
            };

    var sqlParameters = new []
            {
                new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "dateCreated",
                    Value = dateCreated ?? Convert.DBNull,
                    SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime,
                },
                new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "dateModified",
                    Value = dateModified ?? Convert.DBNull,
                    SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime,
                },
                new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "firstName",
                    Size = 100,
                    Value = firstName ?? Convert.DBNull,
                    SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,
                },
                parameterid,
                new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "lastName",
                    Size = 100,
                    Value = lastName ?? Convert.DBNull,
                    SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,
                },
                new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "modifiedBy",
                    Size = 50,
                    Value = modifiedBy ?? Convert.DBNull,
                    SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,
                },
                new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "person",
                    Value = person ?? Convert.DBNull,
                    SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int,
                },
                new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "type",
                    Value = type ?? Convert.DBNull,
                    SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int,
                },
                parameterreturnValue,
            };

    var _ = await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("EXEC @returnValue = [Requirements].[InsertAttendee] @dateCreated, @dateModified, @firstName, @id OUTPUT, @lastName, @modifiedBy, @person, @type", sqlParameters, cancellationToken);

    id.SetValue(parameterid.Value);

    returnValue?.SetValue(parameterreturnValue.Value);

    return _;
}
```

IKATSContextProcedures

```
Task<int> InsertAttendeeAsync(DateTime dateCreated, DateTime dateModified, string firstName, string lastName, string modifiedBy, int? person, int type, int id);
```

Comment: Looks like there is an issue with the interface defintion. Suggest you create an issue with repro details in the Power Tools github repo

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET should be able to create a cancellationToken for you via Dependency Injection.

And you can use an output parameter as in the sample code below:

```
[HttpPost("InsertAttendee")]
public async Task<int> InsertAttendeeAsync(Attendee1 request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Attendee1 Attendee2 = new Attendee1();
    Attendee1.Type = request.Type;
    Attendee1.Person = request.Person;
    Attendee1.FirstName = request.FirstName;
    Attendee1.LastName = request.LastName;
    Attendee1.DateCreated = request.DateCreated;
    Attendee1.DateModified = request.DateModified;
    Attendee1.ModifiedBy = request.ModifiedBy;

    var returnedId = new OutputParameter<int?>();

    int response = await _context.GetProcedures().InsertAttendeeAsync(Attendee2.DateCreated, Attendee2.DateModified, Attendee2.FirstName, Attendee2.LastName, Attendee2.ModifiedBy, Attendee2.Person, Attendee2.Type, returnedId, cancellationtoken);

    return response;   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Made a couple of adjustments to the model class and it worked!

Comment: If there was an issue with the generated code please create an issue in the Power Tools repository